# How to avoid the popup for choosing email when use try to use oauth2 in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I am trying to build an flask app on AWS lambda, which needs to access https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly to get the Mac Address of chrome devices by domain name and chrome device id.

Basically the working flow is blew:
A Chrome Extension deployed by G-Suit sends an request with domain name and device id to AWS(as we are using AWS), then the AWS sends an request with domain name and device id to Google Cloud to get Mac Address.

I started with using an access the directory API as a service account like `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, subject="username@domainName.com")`, and it works. However, I realised it was wrong implementation as the domainName would be changed and `subject` will be different for each domain as the Chrome Extension can be deployed via different domains.

Then I started to use the sample code from Google(https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app), and I was able to access the domain and get the Mac Address of each device.

However, the problem is it requires to choose the email when you call the google api for the first time. But as I mentioned above, this app is going to run on AWS, so clearly users cannot choose the email.

So is that possible that we just use the domainName instead of choosing email to do the authentication and access the different directories? If so, is there any examples or documentations I need to read?

I suspect I need to modify this part from the sample, but I am still getting confused how it works.

```
@app.route('/adminlogin')
def authorize():
  # Create flow instance to manage the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant Flow steps.
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
      # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
      access_type='offline',
      approval_prompt="force",
      # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
      #include_granted_scopes='true'
      )
  # Store the state so the callback can verify the auth server response.
  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)
```

Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: You started off correctly using a service account. The next step is to implement Domain Wide delegation to that service account so that it can assume an email address that is a G Suite super admin. The code that you posted is a Flask website application that implements Google OAuth so that a user can login with their Google Account email address.

Comment: @JohnHanley. Thx for ur reply. But I am not really get your suggestion. I am thinking the correct approach is replace flask with serverless, aws lambda and apt gateway. As to your first suggestion, what if there are two organisations has one domain for each? How can I use same email to connect to these two domains? As the email exists in one organisation may not exist in the other one. FYI, I don't own domains, I only have one domain for testing. In production, All domains belong to their own organisations, so I cannot ask them to enable the API, provide admin email and service.js file.

Comment: There are two types of Google Credentials that apply to your case. User Credentials (OAuth login) or Service Account credentials. You will need to use one or the other that has the permissions to access the information that you require. If you have different organizations then you will need to use credentials for each organization. I know of no shortcuts to get around this.